How to efficiently seacrh for any of array of strings in large binary string in js?
I have some binary data loaded from a file which includes strings but mixed with binary data and created a DataView of it.
I want to find out which, if any, of an array of strings are present in a specific range of that data, and add those that are to an array.
function findStrings(data, startIdx, endIdx, matchStrings) {
  let returnStrings = [];

  ...

  return returnStrings;
}

The strings may be surrounded by any 8 bit code.
The data might be up to 1 Mb. matchStrings is likely to contain 10-100 strings.
Using a regular expression or searching in multiple passes seems very inefficient, so not sure how to approach it, particularly with need to ignore non-ascii characters.
Example Input:
matchStrings = [
    'String1\x00',
    'String2\x00',
    'String\x00',
]

data = '\x00String\x00\x1b\x0c\x00String\x00String2\x00\x04'

Example Output:
[0, 1] or ['String', 'String2']

By efficient I case about time and memory. So ideally it would not make unnecessary copies of the data and it would only walk the buffer once. So minimum additional memory and times scales linearly with the size of the buffer and not with the number of match strings.
A way to do this is as follows:
const matchStrings = [
    'String1\x00',
    'String2\x00',
    'String\x00',
];

function findStrings(buffer, startIdx, endIdx, matchStrings) {
    let returnStrings = [];

    const data = new TextDecoder("latin1").decode(buffer.slice(startIdx, endIdx));
    const re = new RegExp('('+matchStrings.join(')|(?:')+')', 'g');
    const matches = data.match(re);
    if(matches){
        for(let m of matches){
            if(!returnStrings.includes(m)){
                returnStrings.push(m);
            }
        }
    }
  
    return returnStrings;
  }


Well, searching for 100 strings in a 1MB string isn't going to take all that much time.  Have you tried the obvious solution first?  You COULD create a "search tree" from your target strings, but I'm not convinced it's worth the trouble.

Thanks for the feedback, I've modified the question to be more explicit. Let me know if you think it needs further edits.

This is the code I'm using for now (from my question):
const matchStrings = [
'String1\x00',
'String2\x00',
'String\x00',
];
function findStrings(buffer, startIdx, endIdx, matchStrings) {
let returnStrings = [];
const data = new TextDecoder("latin1").decode(buffer.slice(startIdx, endIdx));
const re = new RegExp('('+matchStrings.join(')|(?:')+')', 'g');
const matches = data.match(re);
if(matches){
    for(let m of matches){
        if(!returnStrings.includes(m)){
            returnStrings.push(m);
        }
    }
}

return returnStrings;

}
